# Accurev CLI cat method appears not to follow documented behavior

Tags: command-line-interface, accurev

We are using Accurev v6.0.2 and [cat](http://www.accurev.com/download/docs/6.0.2_books/AccuRev_WebHelp/AccuRev_User_CLI/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm#href=cli_ref_cat.html&single=true) does not seem to be following what is documented.

According to the documentation, the cat method can be used outside of a workspace directory as long as the `-p` argument is provided, but that is not working. I get the following error: `You are not in a directory associated with a workspace.` The command being used is:

`accurev cat -v <workspace name>/<number> -p <workspace name> \.\<file path>`

When I do move into a workspace, I get a new equally baffling error: `File not found in workspace: /-v`

I'm at a loss. Am I misinterpreting the documentation? Are these known issues (and are there workarounds)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the behavior above is how accurev CLI behaves when the user is not logged in. No pretty "you should authenticate if you want to do stuff" message, just nonsensical errors. I hope this ends up being useful for someone else who runs into this in the future. Not fun.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your current directory is actually the workspace directory. Had same problem when trying to run command from a batch file. Issue was that batch file was in C drive but workspace was in D drive. Even after executing cd  in batch file, current directory was not switched. Switched drive by executing D: command  and then it worked. Hope this is helpful.